# insert a space/tab to separate field in a column element MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, time-series

I have a matrix as below:

```
615319419701102123000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000003 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
```

The matrix has 24 column. In the 1st column, 7 digit represents (i.e., 6153194) stattion ID, next 4 digit years (1970), next 2 digit month (11 i.e., November), next 2 digit represents day of the month (for example in the 
1st column 02 means 2nd day), then 123 is the flag denoting it's time series of precipitation rate and last six digit (i.e., 000000 is the rainfall amount). The last 23 column denotes hourly rainfall data in mm.

I want to separate the field of 1st column in to station ID, year, month, day and value to feed into the program, something like this:

```
6153194 1970 11 02 123 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000003 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
```

And finally a time series likewise:

```
6153194 1970    11  2   123 0
6153194 1970    11  2   123 0
6153194 1970    11  2   123 0
..................
.................
6153194 1970    11  2   123 0
6153194 1970    11  2   123 0
```

My primary concern is how to separate fields using tab/space from the first column and subsequently how to build a timeseries out of that? Any help/suggestions on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should produce the output that, I believe, you would like to produce. However, I am not entirely certain if I fully understood your question. Please let me know if you need the data in a different format and I will modify the code.

After running the code, `charMatrix` will contain the data as a character array with the first column delimited as shown in the example in your question.
`numMat` is an array that contains the numeric data that corresponds to the `charMatrix`.

```
%% Subdivision of the first column.

% Read the data.
fid = fopen('file.txt');
charCell = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
charCell = charCell{1};

% Split by whitespace.
charCell = cellfun(@strsplit, charCell, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Split the first column.
charCell = cellfun( ...
    @(charMatrixRow) { ...
    charMatrixRow{1}(1 : 7) ...
    charMatrixRow{1}(8 : 11) ...
    charMatrixRow{1}(12 : 13) ...
    charMatrixRow{1}(14 : 15) ...
    charMatrixRow{1}(16 : 18) ...
    charMatrixRow{2 : end} ...
    }, ...
    charCell, ...
    'UniformOutput', false ...
    );

% Join individual columns with a whitespace delimiter.
charMatrix = cellfun( ...
    @strjoin, charCell, 'UniformOutput', false ...
    );

% If you would like to get the values in the form of a character array:
charMatrix  = cell2mat(charMatrix);

%% Numeric representation of the columns.
% If you would like to get the individual columns in the form of numeric
% arrays, use the code below.

charCell = vertcat(charCell{:});

numMat = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2num, charCell, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help! The data is in numeric format and not in the form of character array. I can directly open it using importdata command from a text/note pad. In that case I am getting error in foll. line: charCell = cellfun(@strsplit, charCell, 'UniformOutput', false);

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think that, somehow, you need to convert the data to the character array of the form specified in `charMatrix`, because, otherwise, you will have problems with precision for storage of the first column of the original data set. The maximum integer number that MATLAB supports is 18446744073709551615 (uint64). If you can upload your data file, I can provide a full solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried to read the data using text scan:X = textscan(fileID,'%s',24,'Delimiter','\n'); There are 24 columns so I put 24 here. Then I tried to convert cell array to character array using char command. I received an error "Cell elements must be character arrays". Any suggestion how should I proceed?

Comment: I h've saved in a googledocs, since I don't know your emailID. Please let me know if you can access:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/15qUfHs6pp_4reGSWM65QgNDkI8mAGSjGUBnPQn-g2uU/edit

Comment: I modified the code to read from the file. I think that the problem that you had was related to the format of the output of `textscan` - see line 6 in the code.